# OBD-II and CAN bus broadcasting

Tags: can, obd

I see a lot of Bluetooth adapters OBD-II reading speed, temperature, etc. Does that adapter read from the CAN bus with **standard** **broadcasting**?

If read with standard broadcasting from the CAN bus, where can I find this standard table of broadcasting? I need the speed value address.

Comment: Speed and temperature are standard PIDs and will be broadcast on the buss regularly not requiring any query. All you have to do is listen.

Comment: can make an example of broadcasting ? i use an ArduinoBoard with mcp2515 for sniffing canbus, where i can find a table with all address standard of CANBUS broadcasting?

Answer (score 1):

The OBD PID for speed is 0x0D. The below link gives all available PID's

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs